# apt update stuck

Tags: 14.04, apt

I've been trying to update my system using "apt-get install". But the console is stuck at

```
100% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)] [Connecting to s
```

What should/can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried other sources? Unusual that you wouldn't be able to connect to the main repo, though.

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure what to try

Comment: As silly as it probably the first thing I would try is to restart the machine.

Comment: I've retarded the machine a number of time, no success.

Comment: This is currently happening to me. Downforeveryoneorjustme says it is down for everyone. I guess it is a server issue on their end.